# Why can I not see the projects I created in Unity dashboard in Unity hub?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a project in Unity dashboard, but when I log into Unity hub with the same login, I cannot see any of the projects I created. I also cannot see the projects that I created in Unity hub on Unity dashboard. I am sure that I am logged in under the same account on both dashboard and hub. I also have never used Unity collab (if that helps).

Comment: Dashboard and hub are not directly connected. I havent tried for a while but you used to make the project in unity then add it to the dashboard through unity

Answer (score 0):

Unity Hub shows only projects that you created using Unity Hub or projects you opened with it. Unity Hub does not show projects created by the account. You will need to add them manually.

[image]